# Scaling polynomial terms in resource selection function (GLM) in R

Tags: r, scale, glm

I'm trying to perform an habitat selection analysis through the resourse selection function (a GLM) with continous variables. I'm pretty new to these methods, and I understood that it is better to scale each variable when their values cover very different ranges.
Since I expect that some of the variables may show (and it is) some peaks in the relationship among dependent and response variables, I added a quadratic term but I was wondering if should I scale even the polynomial term, because I obtain different results if I do it or not.

Therefore, let `animal_cov` be my dataset with covariates values for each GPS location (`Var1, Var2, Var3`), `case_` the column identifying random from real locations and `day` the column identifying if that location was obtained during day or night

```
head(animal_cov)
# A tibble: 6 × 8
       x_       y_ day   case_ Var1  Var2  Var3     ID   
*   <dbl>    <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 839239. 5098518. FALSE     1 -20   467.  241.  Animal1
2 839258. 5098552. TRUE      1   0   456.  209.  Animal1
3 839280. 5098451. FALSE     1  20   462.  215.  Animal1
4 839457. 5098063. FALSE     1  28.3  44.7 -28.3 Animal1
5 839235. 5098521. FALSE     1 -20   467.  241.  Animal1
6 839157. 5099400. TRUE      1  20   209.  379.  Animal1
```

how should I write my expression

```
library(amt)    
animal_rsf<-fit_rsf(data=animal_cov,formula=case_~scale(Var1):day+I(Var1^2):day+scale(Var2):day+scale(Var3):day+I(Var3^2):day)
```

or

```
animal_rsf<-fit_rsf(data=animal_cov,formula=case_~scale(Var1):day+scale(I(Var1^2)):day+scale(Var2):day+scale(Var3):day+scale(I(Var3^2)):day)
```